# Python/SymPy solving a inequal equation with a complex variable in a absolut function

Tags: python, math, sympy

The task is to plot the set of points which correspond to following equation, assuming that 'z' is a complex number (a+b*I).

[image: Equation]

First problem is that SymPy apparently can't solve expressions containing an imaginary value in a abs function, which is really disapponting. So i used a work around that leads to:

[image: Equation 2]

So far so good, now i tried to solve it with "solveset()":

```
eq_3b = Lt(sqrt(a**2 + (b-1)**2),10)
solveset(eq_3b,a)
```

This leads to the Error:

```
Inequalities in the complex domain are not supported. Try the real
domain by setting domain=S.Reals
```

With the proposed change i get:

[image: Solution]

Which is of type "sympy.sets.conditionset.ConditionSet" this brings me no further.

My question is whether there is another or better way to solve this issue ?
Please help me.

Comment: How would you expect the answer to be represented?